# Wrong indentation in .cshtml file

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio, razor

When I use c# code into an cshtml file, it doesn't follow the indentation standard of c#, as shown below it adds three indents. How could I correct these indents?

```
@model Vidly.ViewModels.RandomMovieViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Random";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>@Model.Movie.Name</h2>

@if (Model.Customers.Count == 0)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                
            }
```

Comment: what ide are you using?

Comment: Visual Studio 2019

Comment: Not really, I have problems only when I use c# code in the cshtml. And I don't use Resharper